# More than One value from pick list

Tags: soql, picklist

I have to get records whose picklist value is x and y. I wrote a sqol in developer console I am not getting result. If I do separate search for x and y. I am getting result. else I am not getting any result. `SELECT AccountID From Contract Where Status = 'x , y'`. Is this the way to write or anything I need to change. The picklist status is no multiselect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
String[] values = new String[] {'x', 'y'};
Contract[] contracts = [SELECT AccountID From Contract Where Status in :values];
```

Or

```
SELECT AccountID From Contract Where Status in ('x', 'y')
```